# PostgreSQL - Truncating A Date Within Age Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, truncate

I have the following query:

```
SELECT usersid as user,
(age(creationtime)) as account_days
FROM users
```

which outputs users (an integer) and account_days which uses the timestamp to output the age (i.e. 58 days, 2:31:31.387746).

I want the output to just say 58, instead of 58 days, 2:31:31.387746. How would I go about this? I attempted

```
SELECT usersid as user,
EXTRACT(day FROM(age(creationtime))) as account_days
FROM users
```

but it changes the output to a number that doesn't tie out.

Im using version PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

Sounds looks like you want to look into `justify_interval()` and `date_trunc()`:

```
denis=# select justify_interval(date_trunc('day', '58 days, 2:31:31.387746'::interval));
 justify_interval 
------------------
 1 mon 28 days
(1 row)
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: It is worth noting that the function list (table 9-27) doesn't mention `date_trunc(text, interval)` form of `date_trunc`, it only lists the `date_trunc(text, timestamp)` version. The full docs in section 9.9.2 do mention both forms though. I just sent a note about that to the pgsql-docs mailing list so hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Comment: @denis thanks, i did use something similar to your post above but it outputs 58 days, 0:00:00. What i really want it to do is read 58. any thoughts? when i use interval it says ERROR: cannot cast type timestamp with timezone to interval

Comment: @Stuave: in this case, don't use `justify_interval()`: `select date_trunc('day', '58 days, 2:31:31.387746'::interval)`.

Answer (score 2):

### Date subtraction

You can get the number of days by casting both operands to `date` then subtracting, instead of using the `age` function that returns a justified interval:

```
SELECT current_date - creationtime::date
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

Partial days will be rounded down and the integer number of days returned.

eg:

```
select current_date - (current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 month 28 days, 2:31:31.387746')::date;
```

### `to_char`'s `DDD` format specifier

Alternately you can use the format specifier `DDD` for `to_char`, with the `FM` format modifier to remove the leading zeroes:

```
 select to_char(age( current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 month 28 days, 2:31:31.387746'), 'FMDDD');
```

This will still work for > 1 year:

```
regress=> select to_char(age( current_timestamp - INTERVAL '8 year 1 month 28 days, 2:31:31.387746'), 'FMDDD');
 to_char 
---------
 2936
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just needed something similar, the solution should be:

```
SELECT (NOW()::date - creationtime::date) AS account_days FROM users
```

Output is a single integer

Comment: `NOW()::date` can be replaced with the simpler `current_date`