# Colloquial age calculation for display

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals

There is a column of birthdates. To find the current age for display, the calculation is made as the following:

```
SELECT age(birth_date) FROM people
```

This returns records in the format `1 year 10 mons 3 days`.

I have modified this slightly based on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990161/postgresql-truncating-a-date-within-age-function) to be `date_trunc('month', age(birth_date))`. That returns `1 year 10 mons`. It's better, but still not meeting the user's requirement.

Colloquially, when people speak about ages, in U.S. English at least, particularly for young children, people say "14 months" instead of "1 year 2 months". However, around age four, people switch to saying "4 years". Is there a way to write a fast query to accomplish this? My initial thought is write a case/when statement. But it grew complex and I cannot get the case to work for the intervals I describe below.

Here are the rules I came up with:

> ```
> | Age: m (months) | Display as     |
> +-----------------+----------------+
> |  < 0            | exp. 2 mons    |
> | 0 < m < 24      | 14 mons        |
> | 24 <= m < 48    | 2 years 6 mons |
> | 48 <= m         | 4 years        |
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `date_trunc()`

Although the function [**`date_trunc()`** is listed in the table of date/time functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) as taking an `timestamp` as argument, the manual clarifies further down:

> `source` is a value expression of type `timestamp` or **`interval`**.

Bold emphasis mine.
So, for starters, you can use this form to "round" to months:

```
SELECT date_trunc('mon', age(birth_date))::text
```

#### Specific format

For your specific needs, you need a `CASE` statement like:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN i < interval '1  mon' THEN 'newborn'::text
         WHEN i < interval '12 mon' THEN date_trunc('mon', i)::text
         WHEN i < interval '24 mon' THEN 12 + EXTRACT(month FROM i) || ' mons'
         WHEN i < interval '48 mon' THEN date_trunc('mon', i)::text
         ELSE date_trunc('year', i)::text -- or EXTRACT(year FROM i) || ' years'
       END AS display
FROM  (SELECT age(birth_date) AS i FROM people) sub
```

[**->SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/522)  with a complete test case.

You can wrap that in a SQL or plpgsql function for convenience. You'll find many examples here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to meet that requirement with the built-in functions. At the very best, they'll allow you to transform 24 months in 2 years; not the other way around.

You want to create a pgsql function that generates the desired output instead (possibly as text), or (better) manage this at the application level. Doing this at the app level would allow you to localize it and the assicated criteria as a bonus.

Comment: You make a good point about the localization. I would be curious about other English dialects or other languages to see if they use similar conventions. For the way this app display code works, it is nice to have the database simply return the text age. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in a CASE statement and DATE_PART as shown [here](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff).

```
CASE WHEN age < 24 THEN //Show something.        
    WHEN age > 24 AND age < 48 THEN //Show something else
    ELSE //Show age as required
END
```

Comment: OP probably wouldn't be asking if it was that simple…: `select date_part('month', '1 year 1 month'::interval), date_part('month', '13 months'::interval);` returns 1 for both cases.

Comment: But he could do something like `date_part('year', '13 months':: interval) || ' years and ' || date_part('month', ' 13 months'::interval) || ' months'`, which would result in `1 year and 1 month`, the desired` result in this case.

Comment: Actually, the desired result in this case is 13 months -- and similarly for up to 47 months, apparently. Had it not been, `date_trunc('month', justify_day(age(val)))` or something to that order would have done the trick.